# Is there a more recent zend toolbar for firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, zend-framework

I was looking at some documentation that said that there is a toolbar that you can install for firefox.  It said to go to the zend downloads page, but there is nothing there.  I found a site that had the ZendFirefoxToolbar-2.4.xpi file, but firefox 42 won't install it.  I did quite a bit of googling, but am coming up empty.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.7 of the Zend Studio toolbar is on the download page (http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads-studio). Click 'Download older versions' and scroll down.

I had to set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in about:config in order to circumvent a certificate issue.